# autopct cant be added to axis.pie :: error: too many values

Tags: python, matplotlib, pie-chart

In the following code, i'm just printing the label on the console whenever mouse clicks on the pie chart. The problem is  i cant add autopct to the ax.pie() because of the wedges thing, i don't know how to add percentage label on the piechart without using autopct to ax.pie.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
labels = ['Beans', 'Squash', 'Corn']
i=0

def main():
    # Make an example pie plot
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

    #labels = ['Beans', 'Squash', 'Corn']
    wedges, plt_labels = ax.pie([20, 40, 60], labels=labels)
    ax.axis('equal')

    make_picker(fig, wedges)
    plt.show()

def make_picker(fig, wedges):
    global i
    def onclick(event):
        global i
        i=i+1
        print event.__class__
        wedge = event.artist
        label = wedge.get_label()
        print label
        fig.canvas.figure.clf()
        ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
        wedges, plt_labels = ax.pie([50, 100, 60],labels=labels)# how to add autopct='%1.1f%%'
        fig.canvas.draw()
        for wedge in wedges:
            wedge.set_picker(True)

    # Make wedges selectable
    if i==0:
        for wedge in wedges:
            wedge.set_picker(True)

    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onclick)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to use `autopct`, remember now you have 3 values to be unpacked instead of two, so change your code to `wedges, plt_labels, junk = ax.pie([20, 40, 60], labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%')` will solve your problem

`juck` is going to be the `text.Text` objects of your percentage values.
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't know the concept of unpacking the variables.